# Mouse Wheel Issue

Tags: mouse-wheel

I have a dual operating system on my Dell Inspiron 3647.  When I'm on the Windows side, my mouse wheel works the way I have always known a mouse-wheel to work - when one is moving the mouse wheel TOWARDS you when on a website, on a "Word" document, or even on the Ubuntu Guide when on the Ubuntu side, the information on the lower part of the page appears, and the earlier information is further "up" the page.

However, when I'm on the Ubuntu side and am just checking out any website, or document, or even here on this Ubuntu Help page, the mouse wheel works in reverse - I have to move the mouse wheel UP, away from me, when I want to see lower down the page.

How do I fix this set-up so when I move the mouse wheel towards me, I see further down any website, or document?

The mouse-wheel action on other computers that I've had with this dual-operating system hasn't displayed any problem like this.  I can move the mouse wheel towards me, and it "moves" down the website, document, guide, etc.

I've worked on Ubuntu for a few years now, thanks to my wonderful Ubuntu computer techies 1/2 hour away from me here in Massachusetts, but I decided that it's also a good time for me to connect with the Ubuntu community - I am NOT techie savvy, and need the simplest, easiest response for my mouse issue, or any issue I might bring up here.

Thanks!!

- Donna

Comment: Go to Unity Dash (press Super/Windows key) and search for Mouse & Touchpad. Look if there the option "natural scrolling" is activated.